# Telegram call api or url on website, how to?

Tags: call, telegram

After adding the call option in telegram, it will be great marketing way to let website visitors to call via telegram by pressing call button,
Any one know how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When asking a question please refer to [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but now **it isn't possible** with current [Telegram APIs](https://core.telegram.org/api), but it could be a very nice new feature.
I think you can suggest this feature to official Twitter, or support account.